# Не работает условие if (JS)

Tags: javascript

```
'use strict';

let money,
    time;

function start() {
    while (isNaN(money) || money == '' || money == null) {
        money = +prompt('Ваш бюджет на месяц?', '');
    }
    time = prompt('Введите дату в формате YYYY-MM-DD', '');
}

start();

let appData = {
    budget: money,
    timeData: time,
    expenses: {},
    optionalExpenses: {},
    income: {},
    savings: false,
    chooseExpenses: function () {
        for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            let articles = prompt('Введите обязательную статью расходов в этом месяце', '');
            let cost = prompt('Во сколько обойдется?', '');

            if (typeof (articles) === 'string' && typeof (cost) != 'null' && typeof (articles) != 'null' && articles != '' && cost != '' && articles.length <= 50) {
                appData.expenses[articles] = cost;
            } else {
                alert('Повторите попытку');
                i--;
            }
        }
    },
    detectDayBudget: function () {
        appData.moneyPerDay = (appData.budget / 30).toFixed();
        return alert('Ежедневный бюджет ' + appData.moneyPerDay);
    },
    detectLevel: function () {
        if (appData.moneyPerDay < 1000) {
            console.log('Минимальный заработок');
        } else if (appData.moneyPerDay >= 1000 && appData.moneyPerDay < 2000) {
            console.log('Средний заработок');
        } else if (appData.moneyPerDay >= 2000) {
            console.log('Высокий заработок');
        }
    },
    checkSavings: function () {
        if (appData.savings) {
            let save = +prompt('Какова сумма накоплений?');
            let percent = prompt('Под какой процент?');

            appData.monthIncome = save / 100 / 12 * percent;
        }
    },
    chooseOptExpenses: function () {
        for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            let optionalExpenses = prompt('Статья необязательных расходов?', '');
            appData.optionalExpenses[i] = optionalExpenses;
        }
    },
    chooseIncome: function () {
        let items = prompt('Что принесет дополнительный доход? (перечислить через запятую)', '');

        if (typeof (items) === 'null' || typeof (items) === '' || typeof (items) != 'string') {
            console.log('Повторите попытку!');
        } else {
            appData.income = items.split(', ');
            appData.income.push(prompt('Может что-то еще?'));
            appData.income.sort();
        }

        appData.income.forEach(function (item, i) {
            alert('Способы доп.заработка ' + (i + 1) + ' : ' + item);
        });
    }
};
```

Прошу вашей помощи, скажите пожалуйста, почему в chooseIncome не работает проверка на введенные данные в prompt. 2 часа голову ломаю, а все равно понять не могу.

Comment: Предоставьте [mcve]

Comment: а что запускает сама функция? отображение prompt'ов?

Comment: это целиком моя программа, я тренируюсь работать с обьектами и все вывожу через prompt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`typeof (items) != 'string'` не имеет смысла, потому что prompt всегда возвращает строку (если не было отмены), а остальные вот что возвращают:

```js
console.log( typeof null ) // object (ошибка в языке) 

console.log( typeof "" ) // string
```

Необходимую проверку можно делать как показано ниже, и то в случае, если как-то по разному надо обрабатывать пустую строку и null, иначе достаточно `if( !items )` — потому что они оба в логическом контексте будут `false`.

```js
let items = prompt('что-то', '');

if ( items === null ) {
  console.log('null!');
} else if( !items ) {
  console.log('пустая строка!');
} else {
  console.log('Ок!');
}
```

`!` логическое НЕ: false превращает в true, и наоборот. Можно было записать `if (items == "")`

---

И бесконечный prompt, до тех пор, пока что-то не введут:

```js
let x = prompt("Введите что-то...", "");

while( x !== null && x == "" ){ // x !== null && !x
  x = prompt("Вы ничего не ввели. Это обязательно!", "");
}

if( x === null ) {
  console.log( "null !" );
} else {
  console.log( x );
}
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ, подскажите пожалуйста тогда такую вещь, как мне сделать так, чтобы в случае, если отправляем пустую строку, то мне выдавало ошибку и вновь появлялся prompt до тех пор, пока я не введу информацию?

Comment: @quires добавил в ответ)

Comment: спасибо за помощь)